# Single variable inside an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I basically want a way to write an if statement with only one variable in it, like:

```
$var = "$foo == 'bar'";
if ($var) {
    // do code
}
```

Or to put it more descriptively, 
Instead of:

```
$run_list = array("normal");
if (!empty("extras")) array_push($run_list, "extras");

foreach ($run_list as $iteration) {
    if ($iteration == "normal") {
        if ($array1 == $array2) {
            # do 125 lines of code here
        }

    // Will not always be True (may only iterate once)
    } elseif ($iteration == "extras") {
        if ($array1 != $array2) {
            # do exact same 125 lines of code here
        }
    }
}
```

How could I do something similar to this, but that actually works:

```
$run_list = array("normal");
if (!empty("extras")) array_push($run_list, "extras");

foreach ($run_list as $iteration) {
    if ($iteration  = "normal") {
        $if_statement = "$array1 == $array2";
    } elseif ($iteration  = "extras") {
        $if_statement = "$array1 != $array2";
    }

    if ($if_statement) {
        # do 125 lines of code here
    }
}
```

And I don't want to put the 125 lines of code into a function because they contain dozens of variables set earlier in the code and I don't really want to create a function where I have to pass in dozens of variables for it to work.

Comment: `if($iteration == "normal")` why do you want to change that into something complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to merge your boolean expressions here

```
$run_list = array("normal");
if (!empty("extras")) array_push($run_list, "extras");

foreach ($run_list as $iteration) {
    if (
        ($iteration == "normal" && array1 == $array2) 
        || ($iteration == "extras" && $array1 != $array2)
    ) {
        # do 125 lines of code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a boolean to later test in the condition like so:

```
 $conditional = $iteration === "normal";
```

And then later test that conditional:

```
if($conditional){
    //execute code
}
```